# How can I properly implement a user system in my website - basic guidelines, javascript, node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, authentication, session

Can you give me some basic guidelines on how to implement a user system in my website? I have a static site which needs login functionality so I can show data only available to users that are logged in.

I would like to do this with javascript, but I am open to any and all suggestions you have as I am learning and every bit of information is useful to me.

**So basically, here's the breakdown:**

- I have a static website, complete with different pages and links (built in html, css, a bit of js)
- Also, I have a MySQL database ready
- The next step is making a login system so I can show pages only for logged in users
- What are the steps I need to take / things I need to set up / things I need to add?

I'm very thankful for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check [this](https://medium.com/devc-kano/basics-of-authentication-using-passport-and-jwt-with-sequelize-and-mysql-database-748e09d01bab) out.
It has a pretty good tutorial for a setup that is similar to yours.

Comment: I definitely will. I'll update this comment when I do. Thanks <3

Comment: Completed everything in the article. It definitely is a good place to start however I had a lot of issues setting everything up and some of the code just plain didn't work for me. It's probably my fault, but all in all this is a good introduction. Thanks again

Comment: @benyamynbrkyc glad to hear it was helpful. There are a lot of tutorials in the internet, however the topic is a bit too broad to bundle up a concise answer :)